# Sharing String between two applications

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I have two applications and I want to be able to share a `String value` between them. For example: user changes the String in `app A`, when `app B` is launched, I want it to read the updated `String` (and vice versa).

I was trying to use SharedPreferences with `Context.MODE_WORLD_WRITABLE`, but it's been deprecated.

How can I achieve this?

EDIT: App A has to save the value without launching app B. App B has to be able to read that value without launching app A.
I looked at `ContentProviders`, but they look too complex, especially for a simple String sharing.

Comment: One way of doing this is by launching Activity of App B from App A and send data with Intent. http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/filters.html // Twitter/FB/SMS share content works like this.

Answer (score 1):

One option is use webserver for this. for example store value in web server from app1 and access this value from app2

option two is use content providers. Through the content provider, other apps can query or even modify the data (if the content provider allows it)

Answer (score 1):

Simply put:

- one application needs to send intent with data
- the other one needs to listen for it with brodcast receiver.
- Content provider is probably not the thing you are looking for.

here is good [tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidBroadcastReceiver/article.html) for brodcast receiver

Comment: Does the app that receives broadcast intent, have to be running?

Comment: No, you can register for that in manifest. But! Your app need to be started by the user at least once. Otherwise system will prevent it from doing anything.

Answer (score 0):

Try http://developer.android.com/training/sharing/send.html or http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html to share data between 2 applications